# What happens to a multithreaded Linux process if it gets a signal?

Tags: linux, signals, posix, multithreading

If a Unix (Posix) process receives a signal, a signal handler will run.

What will happen to it in a multithreaded process? Which thread receives the signal?

In my opinion, the signal API should be extended to handle that (i.e. the thread of the signal handler should be able to be determined), but hunting for infos on the net I only found year long flames on the linux kernel mailing list and on different forums. As I understood, Linus' concept differed from the Posix standard, and first some compat layer was built, but now the Linux follows the posix model.

What is the current state?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679568/signal-handling-with-multiple-threads-in-linux "pthreads(7) describes that POSIX.1 requires all threads in a process share attributes, including signal dispositions"

Comment: @steve Thanks, but 1) it is on another SE site 2) this spec doesn't specify clearly, what will exactly happen. What it means, the signal handlers will be called on _all_ threads, but it seems a little bit surrealistic to me. 3) That answer doesn't specify what was Linus' model and why/how is it used currently.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The entry in POSIX on "[Signal Generation and Delivery](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_04_02)" in "Rationale: System Interfaces General Information" says

> Signals generated for a process are delivered to only one thread. Thus, if more than one thread is eligible to receive a signal, one has to be chosen. The choice of threads is left entirely up to the implementation both to allow the widest possible range of conforming implementations and to give implementations the freedom to deliver the signal to the "easiest possible" thread should there be differences in ease of delivery between different threads.

From the [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) manual on a Linux system:

> A  signal  may  be  generated  (and  thus pending) for a process as a whole
>   (e.g., when sent using [`kill(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)) or for a  specific  thread  (e.g.,  certain
>   signals,  such as SIGSEGV and SIGFPE, generated as a consequence of executing a specific machine-language instruction are  thread  directed,  as  are
>   signals  targeted  at a specific thread using [`pthread_kill(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html)).  A process-directed signal may be delivered to any one of the threads  that  does  not
>   currently have the signal blocked.  If more than one of the threads has the
>   signal unblocked, then the kernel chooses an arbitrary thread to  which  to
>   deliver the signal.

And in [`pthreads(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html):

> Threads  have  distinct alternate signal stack settings.  However, a new
>   thread's alternate signal stack settings are copied from the thread that
>   created  it,  so  that  the  threads initially share an alternate signal
>   stack (fixed in kernel 2.6.16).

From the [`pthreads(3)`](http://man.openbsd.org/pthreads.3) manual on an OpenBSD system (as an example of an alternate approach):

> Signals handlers are normally run on the stack of the currently executing
>   thread.

(I'm currently not aware of how this is handled when multiple threads are executing  concurrently on a multi-processor machine)

The older LinuxThread implementation of POSIX threads only allowed distinct single threads to be targeted by signals. From [`pthreads(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) on a Linux system:

> LinuxThreads  does  not  support  the  notion  of
>   process-directed signals: signals may be sent only to specific threads.

Comment: Given the "_(fixed in kernel 2.6.16)_", the docs suggest that the _current_ situation is that: Threads have distinct alternate signal stack settings, and a new thread starts with no alternate signal stack defined. So by default, when a `pthread_kill` signal comes in for a thread, the process-wide signal handler is executed on top of that thread's stack. Is this correct?

Answer (score 13):

Extending the accepted answer, there is a more practical view, what I found [here](https://devarea.com/linux-handling-signals-in-a-multithreaded-application/).

The essence is the following:

#### Signal handlers are per-process, but signal masks are per-thread.

1. Thus, if we install/uninstall a signal handler (with [signal()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) or [sigaction())](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) on any thread, it will affect all of them.
2. If a process gets a signal, the handler will be executed only on a single thread. This thread is pseudo-randomly selected among them, whose signal mask accepts it. **My experiments show that it is always the thread with the least pid.**<sup>*</sup>
3. Signals sent to any thread are considered as signal sent to the main process. Thus, if a thread gets a signal, it is quite possible that an other thread will execute the handler. Best if we see that as if threads (identified by `tid`s, thread ids) would be considered as masked processes (identified by `pid`s), and signals sent to a `tid` would be forwarded to their `pid`.
4. For the execution of a signal handler, in its signal mask the given signal number is automatically masked. This is to prevent stacked signal handler execution in a signal burst. This can be changed with the `SA_NODEFER` flag of the `sigaction(...)` call.
5. (3) and (4) results that in the case of a signal burst, the system distributes the signal handlers possibly most parallelly.
6. However, if we have set up the sigaction with `SA_NODEFER`, **always the same thread will get the signal and they will stack**.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Comment says it might by also the thread created first. Both would match the posix standard, so do not trust it in your code.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. (Yes, I know this is a year after the answer) I am wondering about your experiments. Is it thread with the least pid, because that's the first thread of the group to be started or have you also tested a case where pid overflows. I'm thinking it would be the pid of first created thread, and maybe it's also possible to change this (by changing session leader? something else?)

Comment: @domen Thanks. If there is no `SA_NODEFER`, then any thread can get the signal whose sigmask allows it. Note, the lack of `SA_NODEFER` causes that the signal is masked on the receiving thread until the signal handler exits, so no handler will be called twice. If there is `SA_NODEFER`, this auto-masking won't happen. The posix standard does not specify, which thread will get the signal, so it is up to Linus, how does it work. I do not know, that always the firstly created process or the process with the least pid gets the handler, both would match the posix standard.

Comment: @doman But you can check it, cause a pid overflow by opening many threads with a small `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` value. Or by turning on some pid randomization.